# Multiple callbacks after jquery click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to do 2 things on click. The first happens straight away, then the second thing happens after the first thing has finished.

I'm trying to chain functions as callbacks, but this doesn't seem to be working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    // first thing
    console.log('click');
  }, function(){
    // second thing
    console.log('callback');
  });
});
```

That code only logs the second message. I need it to do the first, then the second. What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Can't you call a function inside first handler for the second action?

Comment: Try to use mousedown and mouseup events, so you can do it like: $('button').mousedown(function(){console.log('FIRST');}).mouseup(function(){console.log('SECOND');});

Comment: What is "first thing", can you post the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this... calling the second function at the conclusion of the first:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        one();
    });
});

function one() {
    // first thing
    console.log('click');
    two();
}

function two() {
    // second thing
    console.log('callback');
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/Lbn8xjh0/)**

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the second function inside the first; in the case below I've automatically called it too.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    // first thing
    console.log('click');
    (function(){
       // second thing
       console.log('callback');
     })();
  });
});
```